# user input of name using getchar() then diplaying the name. (c code)

Tags: c, for-loop, getchar

What I was prompted to code:

> Prompt the user to enter his/her name using `getchar()` function then print the entered name on the screen.

What I coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c;                
    int i;
    char arr[20]={0};
    c = getchar();
    i = 0;
    for(i;i<20;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=c;
        c=getchar();
    }
   
    for (int j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        printf("%s",arr[j]);
    }
}
```

My result is not working right at all, and there are all types of issues. For example, I do not know how to stop the loop if the user already entered the full name. Instead, I have to keep pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> until EOF. Another issue is the name is not printing on the screen again. I believe the basis of my thinking is false with this code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `for(i;i<20;i++)` Of course it will keep reading because you unconditionally try to read 20 characters. Check for a newline character if indeed you want to stop on that input.

Comment: @kaylum would you mind elaborating a little? i was thinking of writing "if(c=='\n') {break;}" inside the for loop, however that was unsuccessful.

Comment: `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < 20 )`

Comment: @WilliamPursell this is the result i get "(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)(null).........."

Comment: i believe it may be due to the need of pressing enter after every character, therefore triggering the '\n' and breaking the while loop

Comment: `printf("%s",arr[j]);` -> `printf("%c",arr[j]);`

Comment: Why are you pressing `enter` after every character?  Just type in the name!

Comment: `arr[j]` is a `char`, so printing it with `%s` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: @WilliamPursell i thought since it is a char array and i am entering a char for every element of arr and its a loop that maybe i shouldnt store the whole name in arr[0] and the rest of arr be empty, idk, maybe its a rookie mistake? is that not how it is supposed to go? meaning that each element of arr stores one letter of the name? and therefore by pressing enter you are moving to the next element in arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char arr[21], c;
    for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < 20; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = c;
    }
    arr[i] = '\0';

    printf("\n%s", arr);
}
```

run, type your phrase and press enter